# How do I set the user's locale on a JSP

Tags: jsp, localization, struts

I have a .jsp page that the user loads directly. The request it with a URL like the following:
`http://www.example.com/myfile.jsp?country=CA&language=fr`

In the JSP, I pull the URL GET parameters and attempt to set the locale using them as follows:

```
<%
    String myLanguage = request.getParameter("language");
    String myCountry  = request.getParameter("country");

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(myLanguage, myCountry);
    pageContext.setAttribute("myLocale", myLocale, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
%>
<fmt:setLocale value="${myLocale}" scope="page" />
```

There are several places in the JSP that then display a message pulled from a localized resource bundle using `<bean:message bundle="ts" key="..." />` from Struts.

On the first request for this page (after changing the language in the URL), it is returned in US English (the default Locale), and then subsequent refreshes will return the properly localized content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do Struts, but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=struts+set+locale) learns me that you need to set the `Locale` as a session attribute with [`Globals.LOCALE_KEY`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/Globals.html#LOCALE_KEY) as key.

```
session.setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, myLocale);
```

You actually don't need the JSTL `fmt:setLocale`.

That said, I'd do this in a single `Filter` rather than in every JSP.

Comment: Oh the joy of searching using the wrong criteria, thinking you know more than you do.

Comment: As a note: the traditional way of setting locale in Struts2 is by using the [*I18nInterceptor* interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html?com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/I18nInterceptor.html). More elaboration in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546961/814702