# i18n Interceptor usage in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization, struts2-interceptors

I want to make a site multilingual.

I have an normal interceptor stack which contains

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
```

A common jsp for changing locale:

```xml
<s:a action="locale-manager" namespace="/common">
    <s:param name="request_locale">fa_IR</s:param>
    فارسی  
</s:a>

<s:a action="locale-manager" namespace="/common">
    <s:param name="request_locale">en_US</s:param>
    English
</s:a>
```

And a simple LocaleManager action

```
public class LocaleManager extends ActionSupport{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocaleManager.class);

    public String execute() {
        log.debug("Change the local to {}", getLocale() );
        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

In the above scenario the i18n interceptor always run for all actions, which is not got solution. Because the locale only change when user clicks on locale-manager action.

I tried to remove the interceptor stack and add i18n interceptor only to LocaleManager as below

```
@InterceptorRefs({ @InterceptorRef("i18n") })
public class LocaleManager extends ActionSupport{
  .........
```

But it did not worked ?! Am I missing something, or should I write my own interceptor ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to change locale then you don't need action to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always run [`I18nInterceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html?com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/I18nInterceptor.html) interceptor for every Action... It is part of the `defaultStack` (configured in the [*struts-default.xml*](http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-defaultxml.html)), it is there for a reason.

It works in a simple way: if there is a request parameter named `request_locale`, it sets the new locale into session. That value will be then read when calling `getText()` or similar functions to get the proper message from the localized bundle.

From [the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/i18n-interceptor.html):

> An interceptor that handles setting the locale specified in a session
>   as the locale for the current action request. In addition, this
>   interceptor will look for a specific HTTP request parameter and set
>   the locale to whatever value is provided. This means that this
>   interceptor can be used to allow for your application to dynamically
>   change the locale for the user's session or, alternatively, only for
>   the current request (since XWork 2.1.3). This is very useful for
>   applications that require multi-lingual support and want the user to
>   be able to set his or her language preference at any point. The locale
>   parameter is removed during the execution of this interceptor,
>   ensuring that properties aren't set on an action (such as
>   request_locale) that have no typical corresponding setter in your
>   action.
>
> For example, using the default parameter name, a request to
>   **foo.action?request_locale=en_US**, then the locale for US English is
>   saved in the user's session and will be used for all future requests.
>
> If there is no locale set (for example with the first visit), the
>   interceptor uses the browser locale.

Some usage examples:

- [Struts 2 – i18n or localization
  example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/)
- [Localization (i18n) in
  struts2](https://web.archive.org/web/20130724193359/http://www.2bloggers.com/2011/12/localization-i18n-in-struts2.html)
- [Struts 2 I18N (Struts 2
  Interationalization)](http://codesstore.blogspot.it/2011/10/struts-2-i18n-interationalization.html)